# Use multiple checkbox to show/hide multiple input fields with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

For each checkbox i need to show/hide values in a dialog.
The code for adding and removing selecteditems is working.

How can I show each input after the checkbox with React hide/show for multiple fields?

The React is correct and if the second function is removed from the JS code this will work with the first checkbox and input... but, I don't know how to write the React code for multiple fields for this React structure.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VEC1.png)

Here is the code

```
    const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = React.useState<any>([]);

    const handleToggle = (record: any) => () => {

        const currentIndex = selectedItems.indexOf(record);
        const newChecked = [...selectedItems];

        if (currentIndex === -1) {
            newChecked.push(record);
        } else {
            newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
        }

        setSelectedItems(newChecked);

    };
```

This is view

```
       <Dialog
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
            PaperProps={{
                style: {
                    width: 500,
                    backgroundColor: "#222",
                    color: "white"
                }
            }}
            maxWidth="lg"
        >
            <DialogContent>
                <List sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 500 }}>
                    {expensesType.map((record: any) => {
                        const labelId = `checkbox-list-label-${record.id}`;

                        return (
                            <ListItem
                                key={record}
                                secondaryAction={showInput(record)}
                            >
                                <ListItemButton role={undefined} onClick={handleToggle(record)} dense>
                                    <ListItemIcon>
                                        <Checkbox
                                            edge="start"
                                            checked={selectedItems.indexOf(record) !== -1}
                                            tabIndex={-1}
                                            value={record.value}
                                            disableRipple
                                            inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                                        />
                                    </ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={record.name} />
                                </ListItemButton>
                            </ListItem>
                        );
                    })}
                </List>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                <Button onClick={handleClose} autoFocus>
                    Done
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
```

Comment: If i'm not wrong, you want to show/hide input field according to their respective checkbox value. For example, if i checked the third checkbox, then it should show the input in front of that checkbox. Which second function you are talking about. If possible, please create a sandbox with complete code.

Comment: @NoumanRafique
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-antonelli-hwjlnb?file=/src/App.js 

Here is the code in sandbox. That is exactly what i want that if i check one or multiple checkboxes the value will show to the respective checkbox. I also want that the values that i input will attach into the array  selectedItems. Thank you!